# C++ and Parallel Programming: Send two instances same class or non dependent arrays to different processors

Tags: c++, arrays, class, parallel-processing, instance

Newbie to parallel programming with a question. If I have an array declared in a class that will undergo some simple math operations, is it possible to send each instance of that class to a different processor so the array for each predefined instance can be operated on at the same time?
I could be wrong, but that seems to make more sense than breaking down each array into segments to be sent to different processors where they will be operated on as each array is far less than a million in length, and I am guessing there would be some savings in overhead if I'm not splitting up arrays, but rather sending whole arrays to different processors to be operated on at the same time.
There will be two instances of the class and two processors.
If it is possible, how do I go about doing it please.
Thank you,

Bear

Comment: You typically use MPI for suck tasks.

Comment: You need to declare the array static and make sure that you don't have data races. Use OpenMP or MPI (or pthread if you really feel like:) )

Comment: Are you working on a shared-memory computer or a distributed-memory computer ?  On the former there is no need to send data around, all CPUs have approximately equal access to all parts of memory.  On the latter it becomes a necessity to send data around.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I'll have to look into the memory, but in a nutshell I have several non-interdependent subroutines that operate on arrays that I want to run simultaneously on a couple of processors. Currently the arrays that these functions operate on are the same length, and that might not always be the case. I was thinking of sending all the non-interdependent subroutines to two processors and once all the non-interdependent calculations are done run the rest of the program in serial.

Comment: With regards to the memory I'm starting out on a humble netbook with two atom processors and 1 gig of ram. Soon I'll be moving to an hp coreduo. I'll try to do a google search but would appreciate an answer to this. I suspect that it is distributed memory as when I run a program and look at it in task manager it appears to only use one cpu or 50% of the total processing power available.

Comment: For this you may use threads, since it is SMP. OpenMP is the simplest and easiest approach, since you have to change your code only a little or maybe even nothing at all.

Comment: No, most multicore laptops, most multicore desktops too, are shared-memory computers. Your question and comments suggest you would do well to review some of the basics of parallel computing hardware, the relevant Wikipedia articles are reasonable places to start.  Then follow @BrunoFerreira's advice and start learning about OpenMP.

Comment: The dates on this site are messed up I answered this question two days ago and bruno and performance marks answers (which reitterate mine) were definitely not there, although they have a date of May 28 beside them. What is going on? is this a fake website?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses. It turns out that openMP was the answer I needed. I've been following their tutorials and see that it can do what I was inquiring about, eg you can run multiple instances of the same class or function simultaneously using sections, or you can split up a for loop and have it run on multiple processors using openMP's "for" construct. Of course all of this comes with extra overhead that needs to be taken into consideration.

Bear

Comment: The dates on this site are messed up I answered this question two days ago and bruno and performance mark's answers (which reitterate mine) were definitely not there, although they have a date of May 28 beside them. What is going on? is this a fake website?